# Calculus I Evaluation of Definite Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

There is a problem I am having trouble understanding.

We are asked to evaluate the definite integral:

$$\int_0^2\sin(e^x+x^2)(e^x+2x)\,dx$$

If anyone would be so kind as to walk me through it, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Have you tried $u$-substitution?

Comment: I used substitution on the (e^x+2x), and cancelled it, and from there I am having trouble proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Make the substitution
$$
u=e^x+x^2
$$
and then use the fact that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(-\cos x)=\sin x
$$

Answer (score 2):

With the substitution $u(x) = e^x + x^2$, you get
$$du = (e^x + 2x) dx $$
and so your integral becomes
$$\int_{u(0)}^{u(2)} \sin u\ du = [-\cos u]_{1}^{e^2 + 4} $$